# How to get uploaded image file format without using guessExtension()?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I have a laravel 4.1 project running on PHP 5.3.28 and I am trying to find a way to get the file extension from a certain image that fails whenever I use `guessExtension()` like so:

```
$format = Input::file('image')->guessExtension();
```

Every other image I've tried uploading has had no problem using `guessExtension()`, but it seems Symphony is unable to recognize the `mimeType` for this specific image:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'herewithme.png' (length=14)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
  private 'size' => int 0
  private 'error' => int 1
```

and my application fails with the following message:

```
The file "" does not exist
```

I was thinking about doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words):

```
   $filename = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();

    if(strpos($filename, '.png') !== false)
    {
        $format = 'png';           
    }
    elseif(strpos($filename, '.jpg') !== false)
    {
        $format = 'jpg';            
    }
```

However, I'm afraid of the random case that a file might cause problems from being named something like `pdf.png.jpg` (or something to that effect), so I'm hesitant about getting the file format this way. Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe just invoke the Linux/Unix `file` command on the uploaded file?

Comment: to get an extension `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` but it doesn't solve your problem. I don't know internals of Laravel , but it is possible that maximum upload file size is reached , set in php.ini ,  may be cause this. Also in your var_dump there is `private 'error' => int 1` can you getErrorMessage or similar on that class object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with substr.

```html
You can try $ext = substr($filename,-4);
```

Comment: I would rather use explode() and delimit by '.', for a more generic and fail safe solution.

Comment: Yes We can.And I am agree its better than mine. It will work with all.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try:

```
Input::file('image')->getClientMimeType();
```

or

```
Input::file('image')->getMimeType();
```